# Can you make another internet?

Tags: internet

I know North Korea has an internet separated from other countries', but some people say its somehow connected to our Internet.

So, I asked myself: can you download sites you want (with Firefox or something else), and make your own internet infrastructure with one or more server PCs and an endless amount of routers?

Comment: Sure you could.  Some broadcast stations use a private network that includes just their music servers and studios and a program director's PC.  Also, the US Guvmnt runs SIPRNET which is a separate network for secret stuff; rumor has it that there is no connection to the WWW.  The Norks, on the other hand, do actually have a gateway to the Internet, and they monitor it closely.  Probably a one-man job since there are only about two dozen modern computers in that entire country.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

An internet is just a bunch of connected networks. There are internets all over the world, but what we call the (public) Internet (capital "I") is just the largest, consisting of connected ISP networks. There is nothing to keep a different group from creating an alternative Internet, but using public IP addresses and ASes already assigned for use on the Internet would preclude it from being connected to the existing Internet. Connecting an internet to the existing Internet would require following the existing Internet addressing and policies, and is really just extending the existing Internet. You would be hard-pressed to find any ISPs or customers willing to sign up for an alternative Internet, unless you have a totalitarian regime which mandates it.

Comment: \*cough\*Internet2\*cough\*

Comment: @RickyBeam, Internet2 is restricted, and the group maintains that it will never be open or replace the Internet, and it does connect to the Internet.

Comment: It was meant as an example of an *attempt* to do just that. As you point out, it's sort of a failure there as it variously connected to the internet. (there were strict design tenets that it not be, however.) As with all things these days, it ends up getting plugged into the internet. (Even the US DOD SIPRnet is physically -- and in places, *logically* -- connected to the internet.) It is *exceptionally* hard to avoid The Internet(tm)